# Insert Xml node after specific node

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml nodelist. I save this node 1.xml.It is look like that;

```
<SALES_INVOICES>
    <employee>
      <name ref="a1" type="xxx"></name>
      <name ref="a2" type="yyy"></name>
      <name ref="a3" type="zzz"></name>
    </employee>
</SALES_INVOICES>
```

I want to load this 1.xml file and after add some another node list. look like it;

```
<employee>
  <name ref="a4" type="xxx"></name>
  <name ref="a5" type="yyy"></name>
  <name ref="a6" type="zzz"></name>
</employee>

<employee>
  <name ref="a7" type="xxx"></name>
  <name ref="a8" type="yyy"></name>
  <name ref="a9" type="zzz"></name>
</employee>
```

Finally I want to save together. I want to save my 1.xml look like it.;

```
<SALES_INVOICES>
    <employee>
      <name ref="a1" type="xxx"></name>
      <name ref="a2" type="yyy"></name>
      <name ref="a3" type="zzz"></name>
    </employee>

    <employee>
      <name ref="a4" type="xxx"></name>
      <name ref="a5" type="yyy"></name>
      <name ref="a6" type="zzz"></name>
    </employee>

    <employee>
      <name ref="a7" type="xxx"></name>
      <name ref="a8" type="yyy"></name>
      <name ref="a9" type="zzz"></name>
    </employee>
</SALES_INVOICES>
```

How can I do this ?

Best Regards

Comment: xml file should contain single root node. Are you going to wrap emploees in `<employees>` element?

Comment: sorry i forget my root element. root element is <SALES_INVOICES></SALES_INVOICES>

Comment: OK, and where additional employees come from? Please show some code which you have for adding new employees.

Comment: i want to put additional employes add after existing nodelist. you can see my example. thank you

Comment: I don't see source of data in your examples. Is it instances of Employee class? Is it string? Is it other xml files?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [XElement.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx).

Comment: The _some another node list_ part is unclear.

Comment: it is xml file. i load xml datas. i want to protect existing xml data but i want to add new <employes></employes> end of the existing employes after that save it

Comment: So, *some other node list* is actually other xml files with same structure as first one?

Comment: you can see under my question "I want to save my 1.xml look like it.;"
I want to save my xml list look like under the question.

Comment: Try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798854/c-xml-adding-new-nodes

Answer (score 2):

if you can make a node

then `xml.AppendChild()` will add that node at the end only.