# How to add new Node to xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with adding a node to an existing xml. I'm not sure if node is the right name. If it isn't can someone correct me please. It is a lot bigger but this example should do the trick.

Here is what the xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

Now i want it to end up like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
        <Time>time</Time>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
        <Time>time</Time>
    </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

This is what i have so far. I want to be able to add the time node in and the value in the code below.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(movieListXML);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
{
    if (movie != null)
    {
        // Do stuff here.
        // I'm not sure what to do here.
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(movieListXML);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
{
    if (movie != null)
    {
        // Do stuff here.
        // I'm not sure what to do here.
        using(XmlWriter writer = node.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("SeriesType", movieListXML);
            writer.WriteElementString("Time", movieListXML, "time");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this question was just answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798854/c-xml-adding-new-nodes)

Comment: Look above to see what i tried it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use Linq's XDocument to deal with XML.  You would need to add a System.Xml.Linq to your using statements.  It would be something like:

```
        string movieListXML = @"c:\test\movies.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(movieListXML);
        foreach (XElement movie in doc.Root.Descendants("Movie"))
        {
            movie.Add(new XElement("Time", "theTime"));
        }
        doc.Save(movieListXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(movieListXML);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
{
    if (movie != null)
    {
        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Time");
        elem.InnerText = "time";
        movie.AppendChild(elem);
    }
}
doc.Save(movieListXML);
```

Comment: nothing happened. I didn't get an error and nothing was added to file.

Comment: Probably you forgot to add string movieListXML = @"c:\test\movies.xml";

Comment: Nope I'm not sure what happened but i got it to work with the answer above. Thanks for your help though.