# Save progress to a text file C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem here...so that's what I wanna do:
I have a program that saves information about user progress, ex: Calls, Answered Calls... and the user run this program every day and save the iformation to the text file. So the problem is that when the user hit's the Save button it add's a new stat's for that day. But I want those data to be modified if user save's in that day 2 times.
What I wanna do is to create a new file where to save the last time saved, and if the date are not diferent Append to file, else modify existing for that day saves.

What I did so far is:

```
string input3 = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);
StreamWriter t,tw;
if(File.Exists(filename))
{
    tw=File.AppendText(filename);
    t = new StreamWriter("lasttimesaved.txt");
    t.WriteLine(input3);
}
else
{
    tw=new StreamWriter(filename);
    t = new StreamWriter("lasttimesaved.txt");
    t.WriteLine(input3);
}

tw.WriteLine();
tw.Write("Stats for Name ");
tw.Write(input);
tw.Write("_");
tw.WriteLine(input3);
tw.WriteLine();
tw.Write("Total Calls: "); tw.WriteLine(calls);
tw.Write("Total Answered: "); tw.WriteLine(answ);
tw.Close();
```

the only thing now that I don't know ho to do is how to add above all that a check instance to see if the user allready saved today info and to modify existing data.

it's like:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("lasttimesaved.txt"))
    {
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

if(String.Compare(input3,line) == 0)
{
    // that's where I need to modify the existing data.
}
else 
{
    // do the code above
}
```

Can anyone help me to modify curent recorded data without losing previous records.
in text file is:

Stats for Name_2013-11-26

```
Total Calls: 25
Total Answered: 17

Stats for Name_2013-11-27

Total Calls: 32
Total Answered: 15

Stats for Name_2013-11-28

Total Calls: 27
Total Answered: 13
```

Comment: The text file isn't a best way to solve your task. Have you considered any database, may be, embedded one?

Comment: no, becose this file need to accesed by other users directly without using program, for example Superviser open the file to see stats.

Comment: System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);
if(fileInfo.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString().Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())) // Yes this file is edited today. Basically with that you will get infor on the file modification date time.

Comment: As @Dennis mentioned, using a DB or excel sheet will be better.

Comment: @ZaraGheorghe: well, nothing prevents you to modify database and make its snapshot to text file.

Comment: You could try [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx) to loop trough the lines of the file. you could then check if there is already a line with today's date, and then edit the 4 lines of text after that.

Comment: what about using some sort of cache that has a persistent option? Redis will be able to do the trick

Comment: Instead of text file, you can output this in an xml file with associated XSLT. When this xml file is opened in browser you can see that in plain text. Will this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I would say use XML, it will still be readable and modifiable without code and you have some neat way to modify the file with code.

With XML you can easily query the file to see if the date of today is already mentioned in the file, if so you could edit that node if not you could easily append a node.

To append nodes to an xml file i would look at this link:
[C#, XML, adding new nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798854/c-xml-adding-new-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, use it like here:

```
void main()
{
   var uw = new UserInformationWriter(@"C:\temp\stats.txt");
   var user = new UserInfomration { Calls = "111", Answered = "110" };
   uw.Save(user);
}
```

Here the class(es):

```
public class UserInformationWriter
{
    public string CentralFile { get; set; }

    public UserInformationWriter(string centraFile)
    {
        CentralFile = centraFile;
    }

    public void Save(UserInfomration newUserInformation)
    {
        try
        {
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(CentralFile);
            var sourceInformation = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
            var userCollection = (List<UserInfomration>)(sourceInformation.ToUserInfomation());
            var checkItem = ShouldModify(userCollection);
            if (checkItem.Item1)
                userCollection.Remove(checkItem.Item2);

            newUserInformation.DateTime = DateTime.Today;
            userCollection.Add(newUserInformation);
            File.Delete(CentralFile);
            foreach (var userInfomration in userCollection)
                WriteToFile(userInfomration);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
    private Tuple<bool, UserInfomration> ShouldModify(IEnumerable<UserInfomration> userInfomations)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var userInfomration in userInfomations)
                if (userInfomration.DateTime == DateTime.Today)
                    return new Tuple<bool, UserInfomration>(true, userInfomration);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return new Tuple<bool, UserInfomration>(false, null);
    }

    private void WriteToFile(UserInfomration newUserInformation)
    {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(CentralFile, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("*Stats for Name_{0}", newUserInformation.DateTime.ToShortDateString());
            tw.WriteLine();
            tw.WriteLine("*Total Calls: {0}", newUserInformation.Calls);
            tw.WriteLine("*Total Answered: {0}#", newUserInformation.Answered);
            tw.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

public class UserInfomration
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Calls { get; set; }
    public string Answered { get; set; }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    private const string CallText = "TotalCalls:";
    private const string AnsweredText = "TotalAnswered:";
    private const string StatsForName = "StatsforName_";
    private const char ClassSeperator = '#';
    private const char ItemSeperator = '*';

    public static IEnumerable<UserInfomration> ToUserInfomation(this string input)
    {
        var splited = input.RemoveUnneededStuff().Split(ClassSeperator);
        splited = splited.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

        var userInformationResult = new List<UserInfomration>();

        foreach (var item in splited)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) continue;
            var splitedInformation = item.Split(ItemSeperator);
            splitedInformation = splitedInformation.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

            var userInformation = new UserInfomration
            {
                DateTime = ConvertStringToDateTime(splitedInformation[0]),
                Calls = splitedInformation[1].Substring(CallText.Length),
                Answered = splitedInformation[2].Substring(AnsweredText.Length)
            };
            userInformationResult.Add(userInformation);
        }
        return userInformationResult;
    }
    private static DateTime ConvertStringToDateTime(string input)
    {
        var date = input.Substring(StatsForName.Length);
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private static string RemoveUnneededStuff(this string input)
    {
        input = input.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
        input = input.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
        input = input.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
        return input.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Let me know If you need help or I understood you wrong.