# how to add a node into an xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am not very experienced in Xml and I am wondering what is the easiest way to append a new node an XML.

here is my xml, and I want to append the 1 node to xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
   <CQPN_ROLLS>
      <CHQPN_ROLL DBOP="INS" >
          .....
          .....             
          .....
          .....
          <PAYMENT_LIST>
             ....
             ....
             ....
             <SIGN>1</SIGN>
```

How am I supposed to find the PAYMENT_LIST node and append to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, XML, adding new nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798854/c-xml-adding-new-nodes)

Comment: What part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load your xml in a XDocument to do Linq query over it and then append the node. Following is an example

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        doc.Root.Element("Style").Element("AdminEntry").Add(new XElement("Message",
            new XAttribute("id", 2),
            new XAttribute("value", "label"),
            new XAttribute("desc", "")));
```