# Is it possible to add a <remove> element to httpmodule in web.config programmatically?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to add a `<remove>` element to httpmodule in web.config programmatically?

I'd like to use program in following namespace:

**System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration**

I've seen an example how to add an `<add>` element.

In the web.config it's under `<system.webServer>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not, web.config is just an xml file so you just need to load it as an XmlDocument or whichever other method you prefer, use something like an XPath expression to load the correct node and then add a new node to it. Your last step  will be saving the file.

This link will show you a way of doing the xml work : [C#, XML, adding new nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798854/c-xml-adding-new-nodes)

Comment: I guess I was wondering how to do it with System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration since this is a pattern in the code. Sorry forgot to add this important info. : (